# if local variable not initialized, code runs error

Tags: c

This is a small code to calculate prime numbers, compile with gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
When I use `int64_t p = 0`, it work fine. use `int64_t p`, it work error.What's wrong with this?

The variable `p` will be assigned by use `scanf`

OK with `int64_t p = 0`:

```
gcc t.c && ./a.out
input a prime:3
i:2 < number:3
3 is a prime, again
```

error with `int64_t p`:

```
gcc t.c && ./a.out
input a prime:3
i:2 < number:3
i:3 < number:3
i:4 < number:3
i:5 < number:3
i:6 < number:3
i:7 < number:3
i:8 < number:3
i:9 < number:3
i:10 < number:3
i:11 < number:3
i:12 < number:3
i:13 < number:3
3 not a prime, again
```

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int32_t isPrime(int64_t number)
{
    int64_t i = 2;
    for(; i < number; i++)
    {   
        printf("i:%d < number:%d\n",i, number);
        if((number % i) == 0)
            return 0;
        if ((i * i) >= number)
            break;
    }   
    return 1;
}

int32_t main(void)
{
    int64_t t = 0;
    int64_t p;                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    //int64_t p = 0;

    printf("input a prime:");
    do  
    {   
        scanf("%d",&p);
        getchar();
        if (isPrime(p))
            printf("%d is a prime, again:", p); 
        else
            printf("%d not a prime, again:", p); 
    }while(1);
}
```

Comment: `"%d"` provides conversion for an `int` (4-bytes) while you want to read into a `int64_t` (8-bytes). A mismatch between types and conversion specifier leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve declared `p` as an `int64_t`, but `%d` means `int`. The conversion specifiers for `int64_t` and other `stdint.h` types live in `inttypes.h`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

```
scanf("%" SCNd64, &p);
```

Similarly, when printing it (using the correct specifier here would have shown you the problem):

```
printf("i:%" PRId64 " < number:%" PRId64 "\n", i, number);
```

Both of these mistakes are something good compilers should be able to warn you about – for example, clang will do it by default. If you’re using gcc, be sure to compile with at least `gcc -Wall`.

Also, checking the return value of `scanf` to make sure it succeeded is a good idea. Exiting otherwise is fine if you don’t want to do any deeper recovery.

```
if (scanf("%" SCNd64, &p) != 1) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Finally, the correct return type for `main` is `int`, not `int32_t`.

Comment: Good point on the return type of `main()`, except that on most machines, `int32_t` is a synonym for `int`, so footnote 10 in C11 [§5.1.2.2.1 Program startup](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1) applies.  I agree, though: using `int32_t` as the return type is _not_ a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

This (`scanf("%d",&p);`) is the wrong code to read `int64_t`.  Formally, you need `scanf("%" SCNd64, &p)` — and `<inttypes.h>` (instead of, or as well as, `<stdint.h>`).

You would probably get away with `scanf("%lld", &p);` since on most machines, `int64_t` is a synonym for `long long`.

You should also check that `scanf()` returns `1` before using the result.

When you initialize `p`, you get the 'correct' part of `p` set by the `scanf()` call because you're on a little-endian machine, and the remainder is zero as you want.  But doing that invokes undefined behaviour.  Anything could happen.  It is unportable (it probably won't do what you want on big-endian machines), and completely unreliable because it is undefined behaviour.